# dnstop with savefile no output

Tags: linux, dns

I need to use dnstop, but from script in non-interactive mode.
I am using following commands:

`tcpdump -c 10000 -ni eth1 udp port 53 -w dump.pcap`

`dnstop -l 4 dump.pcap > dnstop.report`

And when i open dnstop.report file it have empty statistics:

`cat dnstop.report`

Sources     Count      %

---

Destinations     Count      %

---

Query Type     Count      %

---

Opcode     Count      %

---

Rcode     Count      %

---

Query Name     Count      %

---

Query Name     Count      %

---

Query Name     Count      %

---

Query Name     Count      %

---

Source Query Name     Count      %

---

Source Query Name     Count      %

---

Source Query Name     Count      %

---

Source Query Name     Count      %

---

Am i wrong? Any ideas how to use dnstop with savefile?
In interactive mode everything is just fine, but i can't process information with script in this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this tcpdump command

```
tcpdump -w dump.pcap -c 10000 port 53
```

that works for me

Comment: Empty results again. Thanks anyway. May be this is OS related or something else i don't know ...